# JHipster Cassandra Microservices Project - the Generator does not Generate Domain nor Service Classes

Tags: cassandra, microservices, jhipster

I have a JHipster apps.jh file with a gateway and two microservices applications.  One of the microservice applications has a SQL backend (PosgreSQL) and the other a Cassandra backend.  Running the command `jhipster import-jdl apps.jh` produces the project folders and all the front-end code (in the gateway project).  Additionally, all the entities and services for the PostgreSQL microservice are generated; however, neither entities nor services for the Cassanra microservice are generated.

If I change the `databaseType` to `postgresql` for what was my Cassandra microservice, then the entities do get generated.

I am running JHipseter 7.0.1.

Please advise.

My best,
Amar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was overlooking an error in the JHipster output (while generating the code). The error I was overlooking was:

```
Error running generator app: Error: Error parsing file src/main/java/com/saathratri/tajvote/repository/AuthorityRepository.java: Error: Sad sad panda, parsing errors detected in line: 6, column: 46!
Expecting token of type --> Identifier <-- but found --> '<' <--!
    ->compilationUnit
    ->ordinaryCompilationUnit
    ->typeDeclaration
    ->interfaceDeclaration
    ->normalInterfaceDeclaration
    ->extendsInterfaces
    ->interfaceTypeList
    ->interfaceType
    ->classType
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/java-parser/src/index.js:40:11)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/prettier-plugin-java/src/parser.js:6:26)
    at Object.parse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/prettier/index.js:13625:19)
    at coreFormat (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/prettier/index.js:14899:14)
    at format (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/prettier/index.js:15131:14)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/prettier/index.js:57542:12
    at Object.format (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/prettier/index.js:57562:12)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-transforms.js:50:31

At: package com.saathratri.tajvote.repository;

import com.saathratri.tajvote.domain.Authority;


public interface AuthorityRepository extends <Authority, String> {
}
```

```
application {
  config {
    baseName saathratrigateway,
    packageName com.saathratri,
    applicationType gateway,
    authenticationType oauth2,
    databaseType sql,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    serverPort 8080,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka,
    testFrameworks [protractor]
  }
  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    baseName geonamesservice,
    packageName com.saathratri.geonames,
    applicationType microservice,
    authenticationType oauth2,
    databaseType sql,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    serverPort 8081,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
  }
  entities GnGeoname, GnAdmin1CodeAscii, GnAdmin2Code, GnAlternateName, GnContinentCode, GnCountryInfo, GnHierarchy, GnFeatureCode, GnIsoLanguageCode, GnPostalCode, GnTimeZone
}

application {
  config {
    baseName tajvoteservice,
    packageName com.saathratri.tajvote,
    applicationType microservice,
    //authenticationType oauth2,
    databaseType cassandra,
    prodDatabaseType cassandra,
    serverPort 8082,
    serviceDiscoveryType eureka
  }

  entities CustomerReviewsByHotel, CustomerReviewsByHotelAndMainStarRating, CustomerReviewsByHotelAndLastNameAndFirstName, RatingByHotelAndReview
}
```

I had to comment out the `authenticationType oauth2` for my `tajvoteservice` Cassandra service. Now my Services and Domain classes get generated.